# Bulk update via elastic search Java API throws exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Bulk update in elastic search Java Api throws the following exception.

```
org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;
at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:29)
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest.validate(BulkRequest.java:412)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:55)
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportBulkAction.java:299)
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportBulkAction.java:288)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleRequest(MessageChannelHandler.java:207)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Below is the code I have written.

```
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();

    for (String documentId : documentIds)
    {
        bulkRequestBuilder.add(client.prepareUpdate("39302", "3", documentId).setScript("ctx._source.customerName=\"Ramaraj\";"));
    }

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

This the same way I have written for bulk index also. It was working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Note:Bulk Update in java api is added only few days back.

Comment: Did you check that your code is actually going within the for loop? Given the error that you get it looks like your current bulk doesn't contain any request...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception says, no requests were added to the BulkRequest object. Debug if the records you add in the for loop are actually being added to the builder object. Found this post recently with the same issue: [ActionRequestValidationException](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/ActionRequestValidationException-td3648210.html)

Answer (score 3):

**This exception happens because your documentIds collection is empty**.

You should to check if  your collection (list, queue, etc) does have documents before make the request. I come across the same problem yesterday, in my case the elastic search insertions happen in  a given interval (lets say 5s), not very ofter the insertion collection was empty;

**In my case this is a very rare occurrence, and would only happen rarely** (in my case 3 million documents inserted every day), and might be difficult to identify before go to production.

I would handle your exception like this:

```
if(!documentIds.isEmpty())
{   
     BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();

    for (String documentId : documentIds)
    {
        bulkRequestBuilder.add(client.prepareUpdate("39302", "3", documentId).setScript("ctx._source.customerName=\"Ramaraj\";"));
    }

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of **size of your `BulkRequestBuilder`**, which has no requests. Debug if  your builder contains any `Requests`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Exception mostly occurs when you try to save or update empty object in elastic search index. For this first check whether the Object is null or not then perform updation
See the snapshot of my code:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include textual content (code, error message, ...) always as `formatted` text in your answer. Content of images cannot be searched; see also [other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5698098).